# Multiple beans reference to same Singleton Bean

Tags: spring, singleton

I created two beans id referencing to the same class as below. I made bean1 to have a singleton scope and defaulted bean2 to singleton as well. In this case when executed.

1. Will two beans be initialized when i call either of the bean?
2. Will there be two singleton objects created for each?

   ```
   <bean id="bean1" class="com.skanda.spring.core.ioc.HelloService"
    scope="singleton" />

   <bean id="bean2" class="com.skanda.spring.core.ioc.HelloService">
   </bean>
   ```

Calling Beans

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeanFactory beans = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(
            (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beans);
    reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("mybeans.xml"));
    HelloService service = (HelloService) beans.getBean("bean1");
}
```

Please advise.

Thxs, Skanda

Comment: *as below*: where? Show us your code.

Comment: oops..i missed. Added now.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? If you can call a method on each of the beans, then they're initialized, aren't they? And if the two objects returned by getBean("bean1") and getBean("bean2") are different, that means that Spring created two instances, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared two singletons, so you have potentially two instances of `HelloService`. If you had used an `ApplicationContext`, both would have bean initialized at refresh time of the application context.

You are only using a BeanFactory, so you have no preinitialization (no refresh). When you call `beans.getBean("bean1");` Spring initializes singleton `bean1` and would have initialized its dependances if it had. As it has no dependances, only `bean1` will be created, and `bean2` will only be created if you ever call `beans.getBean("bean2");`, or if Spring has to create it to resolve a dependance of another bean.

Comment: My understanding is there can be only one instance of singleton so in this case if the scope of bean1 i.e. HelloService instance, then when bean2 is called there should still be once instance. 

Pls correct my understanding. I am a beginner.

Comment: `bean1` is a Spring singleton in the sense of every call to `beans.getBean("bean1")` will allways return the same instance. And `bean2` having a different id is another Spring singleton. You can have different singleton beans of same class in the same `BeanFactory`. Suppose you have to use 2 different databases, you would have to `DataSourceS` of probably same class. But you could allways differenciate them by their id.

Answer (score 0):

```
Let's take one Example ,

Configuration File (Demo.xml) 

 <bean id="original" class="com.demo.Student" scope="singleton">
        <property name="name" value="Shiva"/>    
    </bean>    
 <bean id="duplicate" class="com.demo.Student" scope="singleton">
        <property name="name" value="Prabhat Kumar"/>    
    </bean>

Client Code :


 ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Demo.xml");
        Student originalStudent = (Student) ctx.getBean("original");
        Student duplicateStudent = (Student) ctx.getBean("duplicate");
        System.out.println(originalStudent == duplicateStudent);

Answer 


Output is false

1. What Spring singleton Says :

" When a bean is a singleton, only one shared instance of the bean will be managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that bean definition will result in that one specific bean instance being returned by the Spring container."

2. "To put it another way, when you define a bean definition and it is scoped as a singleton, then the Spring IoC container will create exactly one instance of the object defined by that bean definition. This single instance will be stored in a cache of such singleton beans, and all subsequent requests and references for that named bean will result in the cached object being returned."

As per my understanding spring singleton is completely different from Java's singleton .In java single object will be available per classloader ,but in spring it's per id/id's and per container basis .
```